# Pandas group and agg to list with sequence count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to group and agg a column to one list, after group I will get :

```
col
0
1
1
1
0
0
0
1
0
```

And I want to make a list after agg: `['0-1','1-3','0-3','1-1','0-1']`, `like <label>-<count>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
d = {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 1, 8: 0}
s = pd.Series(d)

g = (s != s.shift()).cumsum()

s.groupby(g).agg(lambda x: f'{x.iloc[0]}-{x.count()}')
```

Output:

```
col
1    0-1
2    1-3
3    0-3
4    1-1
5    0-1
Name: col, dtype: object
```